# django postgres JSONField | query to check in list(contains) of values

Tags: django, postgresql, django-jsonfield

In **django 1.9**(using **postgresdb**), we're using **JSONField**(in a model) whose entries looks something like this:

```
**Entry 1**(in a row of that table):
data: {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": "value4"
}

**Entry 2**(in a row of that table):
data: {
  "key5": "value4",
  "key6": "value2",
  "key7": "value2",
  "key8": "value4"
}
```

I want to query in for values, something like data__value__contains='value4'

Django has support for "keys"(has_key, has_any_keys, has_keys) related queries

What would be good approach to query for above need ?

Answer (score 0):

How about using an `HStoreField` instead of a `JSONField`, which then gives you access to a [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#values) lookup.

```
MyModel.objects.filter(data__values__contains='value4')
```

As stated in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#containment-and-key-operations), JSON Field only has these lookups:

> Containment and key operations¶
>
> JSONField shares lookups relating to containment and keys with HStoreField.
>
> - contains (accepts any JSON rather than just a dictionary of strings)
> - contained_by (accepts any JSON rather than just a dictionary of strings)
> - has_key
> - has_any_keys
> - has_keys